# TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is not supported in Scipy.Optimize

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

Using scipy.optimise (code below) - for a battery optimisation problem

Getting this error:

TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.

Which came from the minimize function directly, so I'm not sure exactly where its coming from.

```
line 70, in <module>
    sol = minimize(objective, B0, method='SLSQP', \
  File "AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py", line 708, in minimize
    res = _minimize_slsqp(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
  File "AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_slsqp_py.py", line 418, in _minimize_slsqp
    a = _eval_con_normals(x, cons, la, n, m, meq, mieq)
  File "AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_slsqp_py.py", line 486, in _eval_con_normals
    a_eq = vstack([con['jac'](x, *con['args'])
  File "AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_slsqp_py.py", line 486, in <listcomp>
    a_eq = vstack([con['jac'](x, *con['args'])
  File "AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_slsqp_py.py", line 301, in cjac
    return approx_derivative(fun, x, method='2-point',
  File "AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_numdiff.py", line 505, in approx_derivative
    return _dense_difference(fun_wrapped, x0, f0, h,
  File "AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_numdiff.py", line 576, in _dense_difference
    df = fun(x) - f0
TypeError: numpy boolean subtract, the `-` operator, is not supported, use the bitwise_xor, the `^` operator, or the logical_xor function instead.
```

```
TIME = 2
MAX_BATTERY_CHARGE_RATE = 4 #kwh
MAX_BATTERY_CAPACITY = 12 #kw
INITIAL_BATTERY_CHARGE = 5 
BUY_RATE = [0.1, 0.3]
SELL_RATE = [0, 0]
L = [2, 5]
S = [1, 1]

def objective(B): 
    cost = 0
    for i in range(TIME): 
        isum = (L[i] - S[i] + B[i])
        if  isum > 0 : 
            cost += BUY_RATE[i] * isum
        else:
            cost += SELL_RATE[i] * isum

    return cost

# BOUNDS
# cannot exceed charge rate
b = (-1 * MAX_BATTERY_CHARGE_RATE, MAX_BATTERY_CHARGE_RATE)
bnds = [b for i in range(TIME)]
print(bnds)

# CONSTRAINTS

# Sum of B up to any point in time cannot be less than 0
# or greater than battery capacity
def constraint1(x): 
    for i in range(TIME + 1): 
        array = x[:i]
        print(array)
        if (np.sum(array) < 0) or (np.sum(array) > MAX_BATTERY_CAPACITY):
            return False

    return True
con1 = {'type': 'ineq', 'fun': constraint1}

# Battery charge at initial time is set
def constraint2(x): 
    return x[0] == INITIAL_BATTERY_CHARGE
con2 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': constraint2}

cons = [con1, con2]

# SOLUTION
B0 = np.ones(TIME)
sol = minimize(objective, B0, method='SLSQP', \
    bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)

print(sol)
```

Comment: In addition to Chris' answer: Your objective function is not differentiable due to the if-then-expression and thus it violates the mathematical assumptions of the SLSQP algorithm. Since both your objective and the constraints are linear, you can formulate your problem as a mixed-integer linear optimization problem (MILP) and solve it by means of [milp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.milp.html#scipy.optimize.milp).

Answer (score 1):

Is the SLSQP method compatible with functions that return boolean values true and false? I would rework function `constraint1` to return real values instead of boolean values. If SLSQP is compatible with boolean functions, could you point me to the documentation that states this?

When I saw this message, "`df = fun(x) - f0 TypeError: numpy boolean subtract`," I found this odd because why would the computation of the derivative involve substraction of boolean values. After looking through your code, I noticed that the function `constraint1` is returning boolean values true and false. Traditionally, the objective and constraint functions return real values. I would rework function `constraint1` to return real values.

Comment: Yep that makes a lot of obvious sense. Thankyou.

Comment: So, the constraint there (con1) really needs to be an array/has multiple inequalities - it iterates over all of time. Is there an easy way to make this kind of constraint that iterates without specifying the time before?